# How to convert a HTML+CSS template into Sharepoint 2010 template?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, html-editor

For example this template is made by HTML5, CSS3 http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/wp-content/uploads/images/smashing-html5/files/index.html

I want to know how to convert it into Sharepoint 2010 template.

I have Visual Web Developer 2010 Express installed on my PC. and I know the concept of Masterpage and nested masterpage in asp.net. but i'm not a asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Its not an easy process, certainly not just click a few buttons and its done for you - you need a deep understanding of the methods and css classes that SharePoint uses for its UI.

Search for "SharePoint Branding" to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about SharePoint Branding through below:

- https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Design-Resources.aspx
- http://www.thesharepointmuse.com/sharepoint-2010-branding/